# VMWare and Hearthstone (Battle.net)

Tags: hearthstone, battle.net

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 so I'm trying to use VMWare, Windows 7 x64 machine to be able to play Hearthstone. However, every time I load up Battle.net launcher, it gives me the error message "Failed to create a graphics context." (https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/blzbntbna0000000a) I followed the instructions from http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/10467796744 to create the virtual machine and setup battle.net.

I have allocated enough RAM and hard drive space, set # cores to 4, disabled 3-D Hardware acceleration, and installed VMware tools.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) instead of relying on VMWare. Wine runs windows applications on linux, instead of running windows entirely.

Comment: I guess wine works the best for most people, but I've had many troubles trying to get that working in the past =)

Comment: It can be hard to setup, but it doesn't nearly use as much system resources as a VM does. It emulates a windows program, while a VM emulates windows (not really emulation, but you get the point).

Comment: Indeed, Hearthstone runs very well in Wine. But on Ubuntu you're taking your chances; it's not a very good Linux distribution overall, has an old version of Wine, and who knows what it will actually do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You said you disabled 3D acceleration in your VM, but you need it enabled to run programs that use OpenGL or Direct3D (such as most games).

Comment: Ah, that would make a lot of sense! Do you know how I would be able to install appropriate 3D video drivers to resolve this issue (i.e. do I install them on the VM itself or on the host computer?).

Comment: VMware Tools provides the driver for in the VM.  On the host, it's just your video card's normal driver.  (If you have an ATI or nVidia card, you may need to use the proprietary driver instead of the free one; look in Ubuntu's "Additional Drivers" application.)

Comment: Addendum: be aware that sometimes, you may run into drivers issues. On one of my two VMs, I had to revert back to 12.04 because of excessive screen tearing.

Comment: I have an Intel CPU and likewise used the intel-linux-graphics-installer to download the drivers onto the host Ubuntu, and also checked "Accelerate 3-D Graphics", but I still get messages telling me that "No 3-D support is available from host.." etc.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/537787/enable-3d-hw-acceleration-on-vmware-workstation-10-on-ubuntu-14-04 contained the information I needed. IT'S WORKING. Thank you all very very much.

Comment: The Intel driver is packaged in Ubuntu and is probably installed by default; you shouldn't need to use a third-party installer for it.